# How do you handle NULLs in a Date field through your C# code?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I am currently setting the date field to a Datetime.Now which is being done through the SQL query on the database.

I do a

```
SELECT NVL(mydatefield, sysdate) FROM myView;
```

This is not the most elegant approach I can think of. The better practice would be to check for a NULL.
I found that the DateTime class does not support the syntax that I am using for int values.

What approaches have you seen being used? What's your preference? How can you make a DateTime handle null values?
I don't want the `DateTime.ParseExact` in my front-end code to throw an exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DateTime?` is a nullable `DateTime`. You could also use `default(DateTime)` to find non-set DateTime fields. A final option is to use `DateTime.Min` or `DateTime.Max` as a special value.

Instead of `DateTime.ParseExact` you can use `DateTime.TryParse`.

```
string input = "2010-10-04";
DateTime result;
bool success = DateTime.TryParse(input, out result);
```

Comment: @abhi, in my experience it works just fine. I use it all the time. Is there a specific example you can give?

Comment: default(DateTime) == DateTime.MinValue

Comment: @Austin / Brad,
I have separated the chaff from the wheat, but here's something that I was trying to work with.

 string s;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            s =  dt ? DateTime.Now.ToString(): "EMPTY";

Comment: @abhi, your condition here of simply `dt` is not a valid condition. How about `s = dt == null ? DateTime.Now.ToString() : "EMPTY";` Also, depending on speed and timing, this statement may still never evaluate to true (I realize you are probably just making an example).